# sentiment of tweets VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to create a function that determines the sentiment of tweets in VBA. The function should check each word in the tweet and if the word exists as one of the keywords in the positive list or negative list in my excel sheet (shown as positiveRng and negativeRng) it will affect the sentiment score displayed by the function. A positive keyword should add 10 to the sentiment score and a negative one should remove 10. Here is the code that I have so far

```
Function sentimentCalc(tweet As String) As Integer

Dim positiveRng As Range
Dim negativeRng As Range

Set positiveRng = Worksheets("Keywords").Range("A2:A54")
Set negativeRng = Worksheets("Keywords").Range("B2:B54")

Dim twords As Variant

twords = Split(tweet, "  ")

Dim Result As Integer

For i = LBound(twords) To UBound(twords)
If StrComp(twords(i), positiveRngCell.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
Result = Result + 10
ElseIf StrComp(twords(i), negativeRngCell.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
Result = Result - 10
End If
Next i

sentimentCalc = Result

End Function
```

For some reason I keep getting the #NAME? error, If someone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: `positiveRngCell` and `negativeRngCell` aren't declared or populated in your function.  Before trying it as a UDF, test your function by calling it from a Sub.  Then you can debug.

Comment: `twords = Split(tweet, "  ")` will give you words with punctuation marks and smileys appended, also "words" that consist of a single space if there is a double space in the tweet. Looping through worksheet cells is about the slowest way you could design this. Consider a single list of words with a valuation (+10 or -10) in the adjacent column and get the valuations by VLookup().

Comment: @Variatus For sure this is an homework assignment and for sure the two lists in two ranges was a given.

Answer (score 0):

Please place the following in a standard code module...

```
Public Function sentimentCalc&(tweet$, posKW As Range, negKW As Range)
    Dim res&, w

    w = Split(tweet)

    For i = 0 To UBound(w)
        Select Case True
            Case CheckKeywords(w(i), posKW): res = res + 10
            Case CheckKeywords(w(i), negKW): res = res - 10
        End Select
    Next

    sentimentCalc = res

End Function

Private Function CheckKeywords(val, r As Range) As Boolean
    CheckKeywords = r.Parent.Evaluate("iferror(match(""" & val & """," & r.Address & ",), 0)")
End Function
```